# What is the use case for c++20 template lambdas?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

We had the generic lambdas before C++20 and could write something like this.

```
   auto l = [](auto a, auto b)
   {
       return a+b;
   };
```

And then C++20 introduced template lambdas where we can write something like this

```
   auto l = []<typename T>(T a, T b)
   {
       return a+b;
   };
```

Or this

```
   auto l = []<typename T>(T a, auto b)
   {
       return a+b;
   };
```

Can someone explain what is the difference?
To be more specific, what template lambdas can achieve that was impossible with pre C++20 generic lambdas?

Comment: Just like function templates can be useful. And they can be used inside implementations of  class or function templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto l = [](auto a, auto b)
```

This lambda can be called with two completely different parameters. `a` can be an `int`, and `b` can be a `std::string`.

```
auto l = []<typename T>(T a, T b)
```

This lambda must be called with two parameters that have the same type. `T`, like in a regular template, can only be a single, specific, type.

This is the main difference. Pre-C++20 you can probably achieve mostly the same thing with a `static_assert`, but this simplifies it.

Answer (score 4):

One use case that I find useful is immediate call

```
[]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    // ...
}(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
```

pre-template lambda, you have to create helper function.

Comment: Or more generally, non-type template parameters as a whole